# When to use API vs SMTP in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, email, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

Can API be used to replace SMTP for mail sending in Django especially for things like reset password and mail confirmation.

I will really love if I can get clarification on a topic in django. I am a newbie to django and when it comes to sending mail I register for Mailgun and used the API since I have used requests before but picking up django to work with I am trying to do user registration using DJ-Rest-auth and django_allauth and there is thing about configuring email backend using SMTP.

my question is

- Can i do without using SMTP for django_allauth if Yes a workflow how to connect my password reset to use the api for mail.
- I can easily pass in the mail function to serve as an alert in the views when user registers

I know I can send mails using django but things like reset password that has a uuid attached to it how can I go about it using API's

```
def send_simple_message(name, email, phone, course, mode):
    """ send mail after successful registration. """

    
    return requests.post(
        MAILGUN_BASE_URL,
        auth=("api", MAILGUN_KEY),
        data={"from": "mail <noreply@mail.com>",
            "to": ["mail@cerebrocc.com"],
            "subject": "New Student Alert",
            "text": f"name: {name}\nemail: {email}\nphone: {phone} Just registered for {course.title()} class and wants the class {mode}!"})
    



class RegistrationAPIView(generics.CreateAPIView):
    """ The Registration API endpoint for cerebro code camp """
    queryset = Registration.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RegistrationSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            name = serializer.data['name']
            email = serializer.data['email']
            phone = serializer.data['phone']
            course = serializer.data['course']
            mode = serializer.data['mode']
            send_simple_message(name, email, phone, course, mode)

            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Since you mentioned mailgun, I would recommend you use API instead of their SMTP because in API it will take care of SSL connections and other formatting stuff on its own

Comment: You can use mail APIs for sending email from Django, as long as you write and configure an appropriate plugin to handle that. Since both mailgun and Django are pretty popular, chances are such a plugin already exists and you just need to add it to your project. Try some light googling.

Comment: i have made some edits to the question for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not write your plain own mail sending function, you should always use Django's builtin [`send_mail` (or related) function(s)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/), **and configure a custom email backend in your settings.**

> If you need to change how emails are sent you can write your own email backend. The [`EMAIL_BACKEND`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#std:setting-EMAIL_BACKEND) setting in your settings file is then the Python import path for your backend class.
>
> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#defining-a-custom-email-backend

Django can automatically send various emails in various circumstances, so centralising that configuration so *all* email sending uses your configured mail sending settings is important, unless you have specific reasons against that.

Given that this is such a pluggable architecture, and both Django and Mailgun are popular, there are existing modules that allow you to send email via Mailgun with such a simple configuration change: https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/email/

Comment: thank you so much now I understand better